# Vertically align 2 different sized fonts on the same line

Tags: vertical-alignment

Total noob at LaTex, but I'm learning! 
Trying to make the bottom of the smaller right text align with the bottom of the left text.

[image]

My LaTeX is

```
{\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont Name}

\begin{minipage}[t]{14.1cm}

\flushright

Email\\

Phone Number\\

\end{minipage}

\line(1,0){500}
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Please always post complete but minimal code i.e. can you make this into a small document we can compile to reproduce the problem?

Comment: i think you want to use `[b]` to align the bottom baseline, not the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
\oddsidemargin-2cm

You have

\bigskip

{\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont Name}

\begin{minipage}[t]{14.1cm}

\flushright

Email\\

Phone Number\\

\end{minipage}

\line(1,0){500}

\bigskip

You want to

\bigskip

{\fontsize{40}{55}\selectfont Name}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{14.1cm}

\flushright

Email\\

Phone Number\\

\end{minipage}

\line(1,0){500}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Your idea was correct, but there should be `b` bottom, not `t` top. And probably you want have minipage, lines etc. in some way dependend on `\textwidth` or `\linewidth` of your work.